# What's slang for “plot twist”?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Some weeks before, I came across the slang for ‘plot twist’ which I had never heard of.  The word ends with double 'o'. Another example of the 'mysterious word' would be this picture which you can see and read below.

[image: bodybuilding guy in the foreground, and weedy-looking guy in the background]

The sentence where I would like this word to fit in is (one of the comments which I read on the original post):

> I love it when the OP does the ______ for us.

Comment: If you mean a single word, that would be *slang*, uncountable. *A slang* refers to an entire language. Are you looking for an entire language or just one word?

Comment: Do you mean a ‘”switcharoo”?

Comment: I have no idea what the "*oo" is, but i would call the example a 'sting in the tale'.

Comment: @jejorda2 the joke is visual, without the image, there is no joke. Jony Agarwal, are  you absolutely positive the word ends in ___00? Or that it ends with the 00 *sound*

Comment: *Now* I get it, the "oo" is in the middle, something "cancelled" the last asterisks (stars), so I added spaces between each one.

Comment: Are you thinking of **spoof**?

Comment: ... or maybe that is 'a sting in the tail'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually I wanted to make it bold, hence the stars. The 'word' ends with a double 'o' and * represented few letters before it which I don't know. This kind of representation is pretty common in computer science. I tried it but probably failed to write a clear explanation.

Comment: @Jim Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted. Why didn't you make it an answer when you clearly know it's the right answer?

Comment: @RoaringFish I asked for a single word but thanks, that idiom was also new to me.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Oh, we call the entire language as slang, then what do we call a 'word in slang language' ? :/

Comment: @Mari-LouA Did you delete your comment? Alright. Sorry for the confusion. I understand that representation might not be so common here. Fixed that too :)

Comment: I did yes, the comment was really a moan, so I changed my mind, and deleted it. Good edit though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you’re looking for might be [***switcheroo***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switcheroo):

> a sudden unexpected variation or reversal that is often associated with a joke (sometimes "the old switcheroo").  It is colloquially used in reference to an act of intentionally or unintentionally swapping two objects.

Comment: My pleasure. Merry Christmas! +1)

Comment: I had internalized that word as being the same “-aroo” that’s in kangaroo.

Comment: @Jim Nice! I found out the post too where I first saw this: https://m.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/3ua4ik/he_hates_riding_in_the_back_so_i_let_him_sit_up/ after a simple google search, thanks to your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Two slang usages that come to mind (definitions from Merriam-Webster) are...

> [**kicker**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kicker) *- a sudden and surprising occurrence, remark, etc.*

...and...

> [**punch line**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punchline) *- the words at the end of a joke or story that make it funny, surprising, etc.*

In OP's exact context I'd probably prefer *punch line*, but opinions may differ.